# I overwrote all libraries in /lib64 by accident, how to fix?

Tags: libraries, mv, restore, system-recovery

I accidentally used windows copy syntax when copying libraries from one folder to another:

```
mv /usr/local/lib/libboost** /lib64/*
```

This overwrote all libraries needed to run the system. The only commands that seem to work are `cd` and `echo`. Everything else prints:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/cp: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: Restore from backup. Failing that, use a LiveCD to backup and reinstall.

Comment: Realistically you aren't going to recover from that one without rebooting from a liveCD. In the future, always `alias cp='cp -i' mv='mv -i'` — `cp` and `mv` have no business erasing destination files but that's how they behave by default for historical reasons.

Comment: @Mat We tried to copy the folder form another system, but the virtual was still partially broken. So in the end, we had to load backup.